# Turborepo developing package with peer dependencies (monorepo)

Tags: javascript, monorepo, turborepo

I'm developing an npm package which needs peer dependencies to work (it is a UI library plugin - and can work with multiple UI libraries the consumer would install in her app - mui, joy ui etc.).

I thought a monorepo using turborepo would be good for development - every app would be a playground which will import my package while I develop. Only the package will be then published.
Example apps:

- mui-playground
- joyui-playground

In this setup - @mui/material for example, is installed by mui-playground, but I need to import @mui/material in the package code (as mentioned above - as a peer dep), which is the other way around.
Typescript's "paths" is no good as per this comment from docs:

"
While it’s ok for bundled apps to set up paths, it’s very important that published libraries do not, since the emitted JavaScript will not work for consumers of the library without those users setting up the same aliases for both TypeScript and their bundler
"

[Link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/modules/reference.html#paths)

Is there any way to achieve this reverse dependency import?